# jsf 2.0 how to display data from joined tables?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

How can i display data from two joined tables in jsf 2.0?

I have managed bean Catalog(represents table in my database):

```
public class Catalog implements Serializable{



//gettters and setters and atrributes }
```

and i have another managed bean(represents another table in my database):

```
public class Profit implements Serializable{


//gettters and setters and attributes}
```

I have a method that returns query which is joining this two columns(from database) with the Catalog id property.

I have no idea what return value to give to this method and how do display joined data in jsf xhtml page...

This is my method:

```
   public <what return value to put> method throws Exception { 



     connect(); //to databse

     String query="SELECT....";
     //this query is prefectly good, i tested it in sql server, it does the job
     Statement st=connection.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(upit);


     while(rs.next()) {



          //setting the values from my databse






     }

     return <what to return here> //this is the trick part
         }
```

What return value to set and how to display it on xhtml page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class that wraps up Catalog and Profit, or only those fields from Catalog and Profit used in the JOIN.

Comment: The object from the class you have to create; you must provide getters for those fields that you want to display in your xhtml page.